# Homebrew Apache errors after upgrading to Monterey, how to solve error 256

Tags: homebrew, apache

So, this seems to be a relatively common problem, but following the steps other users used to resolve the issue don't seem to be working for me.

I recently upgraded OSX to Monterey on my early 2015 MBP. Currently running the `brew services stop, start, and restart httpd` return success messages, but navigating to localhost or my virtual hosts results in refused connections.

Running `which httpd` points to the Homebrew path at `/usr/local/bin/httpd`

Currently running `brew services` returns

```
Name    Status     User   File
httpd   error  256 root   ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
mysql   started    Nizz0k ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
php@7.4 none
```

`Brew doctor` complains about a deprecated package proj@7, but it's installed as a dependency to some spatial packages I'm working with. It also complains about my Ansible and Postgres config files, but they haven't caused any problems before this update.

`apachectl configtest` complains about the server but returns `syntax ok`

I've tried reinstalling, but after completing the process starting httpd errors with

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/502 /Users/Nizz0k/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 5
```

Which is a fairly opaque `Input/Output` error. Following the suggestion to run the command as root, I get complaints about running as root and this

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist: service already bootstrapped
Bootstrap failed: 37: Operation already in progress
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 37
```

I then did I uninstall deleting the suggested directories, following a reinstall it goes back to the `Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error`

So, this is where I have ended up, a borked Apache install and not being sure where to go next...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanna share my way of *possibly* fixing this issue.

After hitting `tail -f /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log`, my result was:

```
[Thu Jan 27 16:32:18.327057 2022] [core:error] [pid 28368] (2)No such file or directory: AH00099: could not create /usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid.KMq3C9
[Thu Jan 27 16:32:18.327529 2022] [core:error] [pid 28368] AH00100: httpd: could not log pid to file /usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
[Thu Jan 27 16:36:12.775769 2022] [core:error] [pid 122] (2)No such file or directory: AH00099: could not create /usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid.sFmHyH
```

So it looks like I don’t have that file created. So I created it using

```
mkdir /usr/local/var/run
mkdir /usr/local/var/run/httpd
```

Then I hit `apachectl start` reulting in

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

So I changed `Listen 8080` row in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` to `Listen 127.0.0.1:8080`

After hitting `apachectl stop/start` I got error saying

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

So I removed two files (`error_log` and `access_log`) inside `/usr/local/var/log/httpd/`

Then for some reason I used `sudo /usr/local/bin/httpd -k start` to start httpd. If that returns that `process is already running`, simply `kill` that process and start httpd again.

my `/usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log` now doesn’t show any error and localhost is working fine on `localhost:8080` as changed before.

And yes brew services list still shows error at httpd.

Comment: I am accepting this because it has all the diagnostic info needed. I don't really know what fixed it for me, but these would get you repeat the steps I took. Thanks!

Comment: The sudo /usr/local/bin/httpd -k start part seemed to do the trick in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my case (maybe will help somebody):

In my case `tail -f /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log` was resulting:

> tail: /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log: No such file or directory

Anyway, I have deleted `/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid` and restarted the httpd:

```
rm /usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
brew services stop httpd
brew services start httpd
```

Then run `brew services` to check if it's working.

Comment: My hardware:OS monterey m1 mac mini. Install  httpdvia homebrew .  started as root. Its at the ~/Library plist. I wonder is it permisisons issue . Super user cannot seem to change from root to myuser

Comment: Its not resolved . I can restart httpd the next day. It is nornal to test a local host web development.